# limit problem involving a cube root and a square root

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have been struggling with these problems for quite some time and cannot seem to find a solution, no matter what I try (u-substitution, rationalizing, etc.).

$$
\lim_{x \to\ 8} \frac{\sqrt[3]{8x}-\sqrt{x+8}}{x-8} \\
\lim_{x \to\ 1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{7+x^3}-\sqrt{3+x^2}}{x-1}
$$
I am also struggling with this problem, it might be related:
$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2} $

They all seem to be following a certain pattern, which I cannot understand.

Note: These problems should be solved by canceling out, i.e. without L'Hospital.

Comment: graph.tk shows that the first limit is around $0.04$ and the second is $-\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: can you use L'Hospital?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the tag says no

Comment: "They all seem to be following a certain pattern, which I cannot understand." I see a pattern: do my homework...

Comment: here is a hint for 3rd one: $a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Comment: The pattern I am talking about is the difference between a cube root and a square root. (Also, the denominator is usually a difference or a sum of cubes, or can be viewed as such.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identities

> $$ a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) $$
>   $$ a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) $$

will be used in this answer

---

For the first limit, let $x= t^3$
$$ \lim = \lim_{t\to 2} \frac{2t - \sqrt{t^3+8}}{t^3 - 8} $$

Multiply by the conjugate of the numerator we get
$$ \begin{align} 
\lim &= -\lim_{t\to 2} \frac{1}{2t+\sqrt{t^3+8}} \frac{t^3-4t^2+8}{t^3-8} \\ 
&= -\lim_{t\to 2} \frac{1}{2t+\sqrt{t^3+8}}\frac{(t-2)(t^2-2t-4)}{(t-2)(t^2+2t+4)} \\
&= -\lim_{t\to 2} \frac{1}{2t+\sqrt{t^3+8}}\frac{t^2-2t-4}{t^2+2t+4} \\
&= \frac{1}{24}
\end{align} $$

---

The second limit is a little more cumbersome. Let $u = 7 + x^3$ and $v = 3 + x^2$,so
$$ \begin{align} 
\lim &= \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{u^{1/3} - v^{1/2}}{x-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{x-1}\frac{u - v^{3/2}}{u^{2/3}+u^{1/3}v^{1/2}+v} \\
&= \frac{1}{x-1}\frac{u^2 -v^3}{(u + v^{3/2})(u^{2/3}+u^{1/3}v^{1/2}+v)}
\end{align} $$

Furthermore
$$ \begin{align} 
u^2 - v^3 &= (7+x^3)^2 - (3+x^2)^3 \\ 
&= 22 - 27x^2 + 14x^3 - 9x^4 \\
&= -(x-1)(9x^3-5x^2+22x+22) 
\end{align} $$

Thus 
$$\lim = -\lim_{x\to 1 \\u\to 8\\v\to 4} \frac{9x^3-5x^2+22x+22}{(u + v^{3/2})(u^{2/3}+u^{1/3}v^{1/2}+v)} = -\frac{1}{4} $$

---

For the last limit, let $x = 1/t$. Then

$$ \begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} &= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(1+t)^{2/3} - (1-t)^{2/3}}{t^{2/3}} \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(1+t)^2-(1-t)^2}{t^{2/3}((1+t)^{4/3}+(1+t)^{2/3}(1-t)^{2/3}+(1-t)^{4/3})} \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{4t}{t^{2/3}((1+t)^{4/3}+(1+t)^{2/3}(1-t)^{2/3}+(1-t)^{4/3})} \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{4t^{1/3}}{(1+t)^{4/3}+(1+t)^{2/3}(1-t)^{2/3}+(1-t)^{4/3}} \\
&= 0
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 2):

Both of these are, by definition, derivatives.
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to8}\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{8x}-\sqrt{x+8}\right)-0}{x-8}
&\equiv\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\sqrt[3]{8x}-\sqrt{x+8}\right)\right|_{x=8}\\
&=\left.\frac23x^{-2/3}-\frac12(x+8)^{-1/2}\right|_{x=8}\\
&=\frac1{24}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{7+x^3}-\sqrt{3+x^2}\right)-0}{x-1}
&\equiv\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\sqrt[3]{7+x^3}-\sqrt{3+x^2}\right)\right|_{x=1}\\
&=\left.\vphantom{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}}x^2\left(7+x^3\right)^{-2/3}-x\left(3+x^2\right)^{-1/2}\right|_{x=1}\\
&=-\frac14
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can write $u=x-8$ in the first and take the limit as $u \to 0$.  You can then expand the roots in Taylor series.
$$\begin {align} \lim_{x \to\ 8} \frac{\sqrt[3]{8x}-\sqrt{x+8}}{x-8}&=\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{8(u+8)}-\sqrt{u+16}}{u}\\&=\lim_{u \to 0}\frac {\sqrt[3]{64}\sqrt[3]{1+\frac u8}-4\sqrt{1+\frac u{16}}}u\\&=\lim_{u \to 0}\frac {4(1+\frac u{24}+\ldots)-4(1+\frac u{32}+\ldots)}u\\&=\lim_{u \to 0}\frac 1{24}+\ldots \end{align}$$
where the dots show terms with more powers of $u$.  We are expanding the roots in a Taylor series.

Comment: ... Thus the key is the knowledge of the development of $(1+X)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha X+ \tfrac{\alpha(\alpha -1)}{2} X^2+\cdots$, here with $\alpha= \tfrac12$ or $\tfrac13$.

Answer (score 0):

Not a terribly good idea, but feasible: write
$$\sqrt[3]{8x} - \sqrt{x+8} = \sqrt[6]{(8x)^2} - \sqrt[6]{(x+8)^3}$$
and continue like in the Dylan's answer using the identity
$$a^6 - b^6 = (a - b)(a^5 + a^4b + \cdots + ab^4 + b^5).$$